# How to center text vertically between two horizontal dotted lines

Tags: sectioning, rules, section-titles, leaders

The MWE is mostly self-explanatory. I would like to make a command which produces the given output. The command should take a mandatory argument specifying the amount of space above/below the text. The text is lowercase small caps.

[image: Output of the MWE]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\oblongdot{\protect\resizebox{0.75pt}{3pt}{$\cdot$}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cdotfill{%
    \leavevmode\cleaders\hb@xt@2.25pt{\hss\oblongdot\hss}\hfill\kern\z@
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\cdotrule{\makebox[4in]\cdotfill}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \cdotrule \\
        \textsc{\LARGE vertically centered text} \\ 
        \cdotrule
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Inspired by

[image: handbook]

Comment: In the last picture, the dotted lines aren't vertically centred either.

Comment: @Bernard I know, I'm not trying to replicate it exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The dots are not vertically centered.  You can use the `\vcenter` box to align material.  You can modify your `\oblongdot` macro as:

```
\newcommand\oblongdot{\protect$\vcenter{\resizebox{0.75pt}{3pt}{$\cdot$}}$}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\oblongdot{\protect$\vcenter{\resizebox{0.75pt}{3pt}{$\cdot$}}$}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cdotfill{%
    \leavevmode\cleaders\hb@xt@2.25pt{\hss\oblongdot\hss}\hfill\kern\z@
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\cdotrule{\makebox[4in]\cdotfill}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \cdotrule \\
        \textsc{\LARGE vertically centered text} \\ 
        \cdotrule
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for partial solution

Answer (score 1):

I could not get your macro to work so with hrule -- as defined here --

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389279/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cellspace, tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{11pt}
  \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{12pt}
  \begin{center}
    \huge \textit{Edward Lear}\vspace{10ex}
    \Huge\bfseries
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{S{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
      \toprule
      \color{IndianRed3} The Pobble Who Has No Toes \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Congratulations for Edward Lear!

Comment: I've seen that already, not what I'm looking for.